# Adding placeholder attribute using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a simple problem. I just want to add a placeholder on an input. Here's the code:

```
HTML:
<input type="text" name="link" class="hidden">

JQuery:
var link = document.querySelector('.link');
    link.style.display='block';
    link.classList.remove('hidden');
    if(val === 1)  // for a movie
        link.classList.add('placeholder="Add Movie Title. ."');
    else  // for an external link
        link.classList.add('placeholder="Add External Link . ."');
```

As you can see, the placeholder doesn't work because the syntax is wrong. I searched related solutions to my problem but they use a different method like this

```
$("").attr("placeholder", "Type here to search");});
```

but I need something that is similar to what I used with adding style, but I'm not sure if there's other way to do it. Is there a similar way?

Comment: The first code is pure JavaScript, the second is with jQuery.

Answer (score 61):

You just need this:

```
$(".hidden").attr("placeholder", "Type here to search");
```

`classList` is used for manipulating classes and not attributes.

Comment: so there's no other way to use the var link to put a placeholder?something like link.attr?

Answer (score 15):

This line of code might not work in IE 8 because of native support problems.

```
$(".hidden").attr("placeholder", "Type here to search");
```

You can try importing a [JQuery placeholder plugin](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) for this task. Simply import it to your libraries and initiate from the sample code below.

```
$('input, textarea').placeholder();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like the following if you want to use pure JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByName('link')[0].placeholder='Type here to search';
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to put this

```js
($('#{{ form.email.id_for_label }}').attr("placeholder","Work email address"));
```

```js
($('#{{ form.password1.id_for_label }}').attr("placeholder","Password"));
```