# jQuery attr() Method add html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, gridjs

I have a search input tag, and I wanted to set a placeholder. In place holder I need to keep a magnify icon, how to do it in jquery? below is the code I tried

```js
$('.gridjs-head .gridjs-search .gridjs-search-input').attr("placeholder", "<i class='mdi mdi-magnify'></i>&nbsp;Search...")
```

I needed to use this path because I'm using grid.js to render table in my django project

Comment: I believe the answers can be found in the thread of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049731/adding-placeholder-attribute-using-jquery).

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
$('.gridjs-head .gridjs-search .gridjs-search-input').attr("placeholder", $.parseHTML("&#61442;")[0].data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot include html code inside a placeholder attribute you can't use the css class strategy to style its text.

Using the unicode character sequence it's the key.

I showed in this demo two ways to embed it inside the placeholder attribute:

- defined in the html as `&#xf0349;`
- set via javascript converting the
  unicode to string before composing the string

When bypassing the css class strategy, you are expected to set the `font-family` as `Material Design Icons` that I did defining a rule for `input::placeholder`.

This demo uses the input element `test` that the javascript retrieves using the id selector. You should just replace it with your selector `.gridjs-head .gridjs-search .gridjs-search-input` but since I used vanilla js instead of jQuery, it would require you to loop for each element returned in the collection before invoking `.setAttribute()`

```js
const toBaseDecimal = parseInt("f0349", 16);
const toString = String.fromCodePoint(toBaseDecimal);
document.getElementById('test').setAttribute("placeholder", `${toString} Search`);
```

```css
input::placeholder {    
    opacity: .5;
    color: red;    
    padding-left: 10px;    
    font-family: "Material Design Icons";
}

div{
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.9.96/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label for="test">This placeholder was set with javascript:</label>
  <br>  
  <input type="text" id="test">  
</div>

<div>
  <label for="test2">This placeholder was set via html:</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="test2" placeholder="&#xf0349; Search">  
</div>

<div>
  <label for="test3">This is the icon via css:</label>
  <br>
  <i class='mdi mdi-magnify'></i>
</div>
```